# Value from browser to commandline

Tags: python, browser, command-line-interface, bookmarklet

I'm looking to pass values from a browser bookmarklet to the command-line (OS X). What would be the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the bookmarklet sets a value in 'window', it's possible to use OS X Yosemite's "Script Editor" and JavaScript as the language and pass the value along to the commandline.

```
// activate this script with hotkey
// ...

function valueToCli(input){

    var Cli = new Application("Terminal");
    Cli.activate();

    // run shellscript or whatever...
    Cli.doScript("echo " + input)
}

// init
(function (){

    var Safari = new Application("Safari");
    Safari.activate();

    // get json from custom obj: window.cttr 
    var browservalue = Safari.doJavaScript('JSON.stringify(window.cttr)', {
        in: Safari.windows[0].tabs[0]
    });

    // send values along...
    valueToCli(browservalue);

})();
```

Comment: Simple example, script could be improved.